# How to find Complexity?

Tags: for-loop, big-o

How to find the time complexity {Big-Oh} of the following function?

```
function(int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = i; j < i*i; j++){
       if (j%i == 0){
         for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
            printf(" * ");
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer for this is O(n^5) but I don't know how to find that.

Comment: Either homework or at least cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is not the homework. In fact, the answer for this is O(n^5) but I don't know how. @MartinThurau

Comment: I think that it is O(n^5), 1st loop N, 2nd loop N^2 and 3rd loop N^2

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis, How you fond that? It is correct.

Comment: @DOSHI The first loop is N. Second loop the max value of j is i*i => n*n so it is n^2. Third loop, the max value of k is j, which is n*n so n^2. So n * n^2 * n^2 is n^5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that complexity is O(n^5).

```
function(int n) {                
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){           // N, max value of i is n
    for (int j = i; j < i*i; j++){       // N^2, max value of j is n*n
       if (j%i == 0){
         for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){     // N^2, max value of k is n*n
            printf(" * ");
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The first loop is N. Second loop the max value of j is i*i => n*n so it is n^2. Third loop, the max value of k is j, which is n*n so n^2. So n * n^2 * n^2 is n^5

Comment: Thanks, just got confused with if statement in middle.

Comment: Although formally correct, this bound is not the tightest one. Complexity is also O(n^4), as the innermost loop is executed every `i-th` iteration.